# Returning generic type of a given interface in c#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Suppose I have the following setup.

```
Interface IDALModel {}
```

Various classes implement this interface as so...

```
class AddressModel : IDALModel 
{
    public int AddressId {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
}

class AccountModel : IDALModel
{
    public int AccountId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class TenantModel : IDALModel
{
    public int TenantId {get;set;}
    public KeyedCollection<int, AddressModel> Addresses {get;set;}
}
```

in another class I have a method that should return an instance of a class in a generic way.

```
class SomeClass
{
    internal DataFieldBuilder<IDALModel> Embed<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> embed, string alias = "")
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(embed);
        Type type = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[1];
        DataFieldBuilder<IDALModel> returnObject = new DataFieldBuilder<type>();
    }

    private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> field)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
        if (field.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            propertyInfo = ((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)field.Body).Operand).Member as PropertyInfo;
        }
        else
        {
            propertyInfo = ((MemberExpression)field.Body).Member as PropertyInfo;
        }

        return propertyInfo;
    }
}
```

The `Embed` method is called from elsewhere as such

```
DataFieldBuilder<IDALModel> Addresses = test.Embed<TenantModel>(t => t.Addresses);
```

What I am trying to do in the embed method is extract the underlying type `AddressModel` from the property `TenantModel.Addresses` and create an instance of `DataFieldBuilder<AddressModel>`

This fails on the line

```
DataFieldBuilder<IDALModel> returnObject = new DataFieldBuilder<type>();
```

with the message "Cannot implicitly convert type `DataFieldBuilder<AddressModel>` to `DataFieldBuilder<IDALModel>`

I was hoping that since the interface IDALModel is implemented by AddressModel it would work.  Not sure what I am missing here.

For testing I even tried hard-coding some examples such as

```
DataFieldBuilder<IDALModel> returnObject = new DataFieldBuilder<AddressModel>();
```

and this also gives the same error.

Comment: what is `DataFieldBuilder`?

Comment: Something like `DataFieldBuilder<IDALModel> returnObject = new DataFieldBuilder<AddressModel>();` is only possible if `DataFieldBuilder<>` is a [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) interface. Vsevolod Goloviznin's solution is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a generic method definition and enforce an interface constraint on it:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public DataFieldBuilder<T> Embed<T>() where T: IDALModel
    {
        var returnObject = new DataFieldBuilder<T>();
        return returnObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: My actual solution is more complex.  I attempting to simplify I may have gone too far.  I updated my question with a more complete representation of my code.

Comment: How do you use your `Embed` method?

Answer (score 0):

You want covariance:

```
public IDataFieldBuilder<IDALModel> Embed<T>() where T : IDALModel
{
    IDataFieldBuilder<IDALModel> returnObject = (IDataFieldBuilder<IDALModel>)new DataFieldBuilder<T>();
    return returnObject;
}

interface IDALModel {}

class AddressModel : IDALModel 
{
    public int AddressId {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
}

class AccountModel : IDALModel
{
    public int AccountId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class DataFieldBuilder<T> : IDataFieldBuilder<T>
{

}

interface IDataFieldBuilder<out T>
{

}
```

Comment: This assumes the OP can change `DataFieldBuilder` and if they can, that it makes sense to make it covariant, which might not be true.

Comment: I can change DataFieldBuilder.  I had looked at the c#4 covariance and I was not sure that it was the right solution.  Digging in more now that I have an example that seems to match my implementation.